# String concatenation with Twig

Tags: string, twig, concatenation

This is not a major problem but there is a better way to concatenate a string like this one :

```
{{ "© " ~ "now"|date("Y") ~ " " ~ site.name ~ " " ~ __( "Tous droits réservés", "NAMEOFMYSITE" ) }}
```

Especially the blank character between variables.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array and the filter [`join`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/join.html), e.g.

```
{{ [ '©', "NOW"|date('Y'), site.name ]|join(' ') }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/4slten)

Comment: Absolutely, thanks.